# Save and Load Keras always error model with 0 layers

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am train model with Keras Sequential and trying to save and then load again for predict result. But I always got error Model with 0 layers. There is my code:

My Model:

```py
model = Sequential()
model.add(InputLayer(input_shape=[64, 64, 1]))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=5, strides=1, padding='same',
                 activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=5, padding='same'))

model.add(Conv2D(filters=50, kernel_size=5, strides=1, padding='same',
                 activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=5, padding='same'))

model.add(Conv2D(filters=80, kernel_size=5, strides=1, padding='same',
                 activation='relu'))
model.add(MaxPool2D(pool_size=5, padding='same'))

model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(rate=0.5))
model.add(Dense(5, activation='softmax'))
optimizer = Adam(lr=1e-3)

model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x=tr_img_data, y=tr_lbl_data, epochs=50, batch_size=100)
model.summary()
```

1. Save with Model weight:

```py
model_json = model.to_json()
with open("model.json", "w") as json_file:
    json_file.write(model_json)

model.save_weights("model.h5")
```

Load:

```py
def loadModel(jsonStr, weightStr):
    json_file = open(jsonStr, 'r')
    loaded_nnet = json_file.read()
    json_file.close()

    serve_model = tf.keras.models.model_from_json(loaded_nnet)
    serve_model.load_weights(weightStr)

    optimizer = Adam(lr=1e-3)

    serve_model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
    return serve_model

model = loadModel('model.json', 'model.h5')
```

2. Try with save all Model H5

```py
model.save('model.h5')

#load model
load_model = load_model('model.h5')
```

There all always getting error:
ValueError: You are trying to load a weight file containing 5 layers into a model with 0 layers

Comment: Try removing the `InputLayer` from the `Sequential` model. To specify the input shape, use the `input_shape=` flag in the 1st `Conv2D` layer.

Comment: Thanks it's working